# How can I print the lines between line numbers 10 and 25?

Tags: perl

I have a text file. How can I print everything between line 10 and line 25 using Perl?

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as "unclear;" it's about as clear as a question can get. I could certainly understand downvoting for lack of research effort, but not closing. Voted to reopen.

Answer (score 14):

```
perl -ne'print if 10..25'
```

which is short for

```
perl -ne'print if $. == 10 .. $. == 25'
```

which is effectively

```
perl -ne'print if $. >= 10 && $. < 25'
```

which can be optimized to

```
perl -ne'
   next if $. < 10;
   last if $. > 25;
   print
'
```

Comment: Why does Perl use `$.` as the default variable and not `$_`?

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger $. is not the default variable but the variable to get the number of current line, see `perldoc perlvar`

Comment: @René From [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators): "If either operand of scalar `..` is a constant expression, that operand is considered true if it is equal (`==`) to the current input line number (the `$.` variable)."

Comment: @René Nyffenegger, The only default variable used in that code is `$_`. (`print;` defaults to `print($_);`.) You seem to be asking "why does `10` mean `$. == 10` instead of <some unspecified expression that uses `$_`>?" Because doing `print if 10..25;` is useful. Perhaps what you had in mind is useful too, but you didn't mention what it is. Keep in mind that you aren't prevented from using `$_` or using operators that default to using `$_`. (e.g. `print if /BEGIN/ .. /END/;`)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is (if using *nix)

```
my @lines = `head -25 filename | tail -15`
```

Comment: Hmmmmm. Not very perlish